# Why can't C++20 compliant compilers detect memory leaks?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, c++20

In C++20 we can allocate memory in `constexpr` contexts as long as the memory is freed within the context — i.e this is valid:

```
constexpr int* g(){
    int* p = new int(100);
    return p;
}

constexpr int f(){
    int* ret = g();
    int i = *ret;
    delete ret;
    return i;
}
static_assert(f() == 100);
```

Whereas this won't compile:

```
constexpr int* g(){
    int* p = new int(100);
    return p;
}

constexpr int f(){
    int* ret = g();
    int i = *ret;
    return i;
}
static_assert(f() == 100);
```

with the error:

```
error: '(f() == 100)' is not a constant expression because allocated storage has not been deallocated
```

Now this obviously means that the compiler is able to keep track of allocations and deallocations — at least in a `constexpr` context.

I can see how the compiler, being in control of allocations at compile-time, is better able to keep track of memory leaks, and of course, this says nothing of out-of-bounds accesses, use after frees, double frees etc, but surely the functionality that allows compile-time `constexpr` leak detection could be extended to some degree of *general* compile-time leak detection too?

Hence my question: Is there some fundamental limitation that prevents the compiler from performing leak-detection in non-`constexpr` contexts at compile time, or was the feature simply deemed unnecessary?

Comment: Because compilers deals with compile-time issues, while memory leaks are generally a run-time issue. It's not up to the compiler to perform deep static analysis of code.

Comment: `compile-time constexpr leak detection could be extended to some degree of general compile-time leak detection too?` no, check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

Comment: I believe that C++ compilers are quite stupid. e.g. why do I need to tell them that a function exists (by including a header or by forward declaration)? If I call a function, they could just assume that the function exists. Why do I need to promise that before I call the function. In the end my promise is worth nothing and it won't link anyway.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Of course. But address sanitisers typically work at runtime

Comment: Also remember that compilers only deals with single [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)), anything happening in another TU is simply unknown to the compiler. If one translation unit allocate the memory, but another uses and doesn't free the memory, how would the compiler know that there's a leak?

Comment: Why can't a compiler recognize that my local `static const vector<int>` with 7 elements in it is essentially the same as an `array<int, 7>` which is 4 times faster? I think we need to wait for another 10 years or so until compilers are really smart.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I don't know why you think `std::array` is '4 times faster' than `std::vector` — real life performance should be nearly identical. But the inherent difference between vector and array is that the size of an array is part of it's type, i.e. `is_same_v<array<int,2>, array<int,3>> == false` and that's important. My function may only want to accept arrays of a fixed size, for instance, or at least to know the size at compile time.

Comment: @ThomasWeller C++ not only needs to know the function exists, it also needs to know the types and default values of the parameters.  That way it can do type conversion or substitute a default if it needs to.

Comment: @MarkRansom Precisely, and anyone who's worked on a large enough C++ codebase will agree that identifying functions/types without headers/forward-declaration is not worth parsing files twice to find the signatures.

Comment: Don't use the parts of the language that are easy to cause a leak, then it'll be harder (but not impossible, alas) to have a leak.

Comment: @IłyaBursov I may be wrong here, but the Halting problem implies that we can't always *definitively prove* that a program/subroutine doesn't leak, but that we can identify leaks where they do exist — the compiler could well be conservative and just give warnings where a leak *is* found, but not say anything about whether there are *definitely* no leaks. That would still save a lot of programmer hours, without promising anything we can't.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude (re. your first comment) that's fair enough. In which case you are saying it's a design decision then? If you have any sources to back that, I'd be happy to accept that as an answer :))

Comment: @ThomasWeller: "*Why can't a compiler recognize that my local static const vector<int> with 7 elements in it is essentially the same as an array<int, 7> which is 4 times faster?*" Because "essentially the same" is not "the same". It's like saying that taking the bus is "essentially the same" as driving a car. Yes, you still get to your destination, but the mechanics of that process are different. Compilers deal with mechanics, not the destination.

Comment: @DividedByZero there are static analysis tools for such partial detection, like [quick finding in google](https://pvs-studio.com/en/blog/posts/cpp/0543/), but as they mention - dynamic tools are much better (though still not 100% accurate because of halting problem)

Comment: Side note: sometimes leaks are intentional and useful. For example, leaking a large data structure at shutdown can be an excellent way to shut down faster if you know that running the destructors is not relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> surely the functionality that allows compile-time constexpr leak detection could be extended to some degree of general compile-time leak detection too?

No, it can't.

Compile-time code execution means that the *compiler* is executing the code. That is the "functionality that allows compile-time constexpr leak detection": the fact that the compiler is doing it.

Non-compile-time execution is governed by the machine code generated by the compiler. By the time the code is executed, the compiler is long-since out of the picture. In order to have leak detection, the compiler would have to generate a bunch of *extra code* into this machine code to do the checking. Which would be slow.

Furthermore, compile-time code is necessarily limited. Most of the tricks that make this hard are expressly forbidden. Chucking `reinterpret_cast` and its equivalents *alone* removes an entire layer of complexity from the problem. You can't throw exceptions either, so that's another source of leak-detection difficulties you don't have to consider. Most of the things that make leak detection hard simply cannot be done in `constexpr` code.